# Algebra, find a base.

Tags: calculus

**Is it possible to find a base of a set** $A=\{(x,y,z) : x + y+z=a, a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ ?

I try and I have:

$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\a-x-y\end{bmatrix}= x \cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix} + y\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}+a\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} $ where $x,y \in \mathbb{C} , a \in \mathbb{R} $

But I don't know if it gives me a base. Is there a problem with: $x,y \in\mathbb{C}$ Or maybe the base doesn't exist?

Comment: What do you mean by a base? If $a\ne 0$ then $A$ is not a subspace.

Comment: Could you explain? How base is connected to a subspace? If A is not a subspace of $R^{3} $ it has no base? It is slippery for me.

Comment: The definition of $A$ says nothing about $z$ having to be a real number. For example, $u=\left(1+i,1+i, 1-2i\right)$ is an element of $A$.

Comment: Seconding mfl's query. Is the number $a$ fixed or not? Your notation most definitely suggests it is, but then the set $A$ is not a subspace, and the question is meaningless. Furthermore, this has nothing to do with calculus. This is linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Show that the following is a linear space and find a basis.
\begin{equation}
A=\{(x,y,z) : x + y+z=a, a \in \mathbb{R}\}\text{ where }x,y,z\in\mathbb{C}
\end{equation}
Suppose $x + y+z\in A$ and $x + y+z=a$.
Let $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $c(x+y+z)=ca\in\mathbb{R}$ so $A$ is closed under scalar multiplication.
Let $u+v+w\in A$ and $u+v+w=b$. Then $(x+y+z)+(u+v+w)=a+b\in\mathbb{R}$ so $A$ is closed under addition. Thus $A$ is a linear space.

Let $x\in A$ and $a_1,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_2\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

\begin{equation}
x=\left(\begin{array}{rcr}
a_1&+&b_1i\\
a_2&+&b_2i\\
a_3&-&(b_1+b_2)i
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

Express $x$ in the form
\begin{equation}
x=\left(\begin{array}{c}
a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\b_1i\\b_2i\\-(b_1+b_2)i
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

Then $x$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the following five basis vectors.

\begin{equation}
x=a_1\left(
\begin{array}{r}
1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0
\end{array}\right)
+a_2\left(\begin{array}{r}
0\\1\\0\\0\\0\\0
\end{array}\right)
+a_3\left(\begin{array}{r}
0\\0\\1\\0\\0\\0
\end{array}\right)
+b_1\left(\begin{array}{r}
0\\0\\0\\i\\0\\-i
\end{array}\right)
+b_2\left(\begin{array}{r}
0\\0\\0\\0\\i\\-i
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: So each vector subspace is a vector space. From definition we can think of a base only in contex of vextor space. But if the question were "show that A is a linear subspace of $ \mathbb{R}^{3} $ and find a basis" is it possible to solve it? Can it be a subspace only for certain $a \in R$ in this case $ a=0  $

Comment: I know that this $a=0$ we have from terms for subspace $\vec{u} , \vec{v} \in U$  From this $\vec{u} + \vec{v} \in U$  so $2a=a $ and $a=0$

Comment: This particular space $A$ cannot be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ since it has $5$ dimensions. Only if $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$ but then $A=\mathbb{R}^3$. If $a=0$ then $a_3=-a_1-a_2$ and you get a four dimensional space $x=a_1(1,0,-1,0,0,0)^T+a_2(0,1,-1,0,0,0)^T+b_1(0,0,0,i,0,-i)^T+b_2(0,0,0,0,i,-i)^T$.

Comment: If the requirement is that $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a=0$ then $A$ is a two dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with basis $\{(1,0,-1)^T,(0,1,-1)^T$.